# i want json array like["ajsa","ajhsahs"]

Tags: javascript, json

```
function createJSON() {
    jsonObj = [];
    $("input[class=email]").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("title");
        var email = $(this).val();
        item = {}
        item["title"] = id;
        item["email"] = email;
        jsonObj.push(item);
    });
    console.log(jsonObj);
}
```

I tried this  but I want json array like `["ajsa","ajhsahs"]`.  How can achieve this? I tried to do it with key but I don't need key I only need value. The javascript array should should be converted to json array.

Comment: Add the following statement when you have the json object ready `jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);`

Answer (score 0):

what you mean when you say value? use this for array of emails:

```
function createJSON() {
    jsonObj = [];
    $("input[class=email]").each(function () {
        var email = $(this).val();
        jsonObj.push(email);
    });
    console.log(jsonObj);
    //and if you want it in string:
    var stringObj = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    return jsonObj;
}
```